# Take string length and reverse in 8086 emulator

Tags: string, assembly, reverse, x86-16, emu8086

Can anyone help me to reverse this string?

Here is my code

```
include 'emu8086.inc'    

 PRINTN 'Enter length of string'
 mov ah,1h
 int 21h

 printn                 
 
 print "Enter String here: "
 mov cl,al
 sub cl,'0'         
 mov dl,cl           
 mov bx,0
 
 
 p1:  
 
 mov ah,1h
 int 21h             
 
 mov [bx],ax        
 inc bx             
 dec cl
 cmp cl,0           
 jne p1       
 
 
 printn
 PRINT 'inputted string : '
 
 mov cl,dl
 mov bx,0

 output:
 mov dl,[bx]
 
 mov ah,2h
 int 21h    
 
 inc bx   
 dec cl
 cmp cl,0  
 jne output
 printn     
 
 mov ax, 4c00h  
 int 21h

ret
```

Comment: Loop backwards from the end instead of forwards.  You're already counting down `cl`, just count down `bx` as well.  After storing the last byte of input, `bx` is already pointing to the end of your buffer, so you already have a pointer to the end if you leave `bx` unmodified between the loops.

Answer (score 1):

- You are storing the string at address 0 (`mov bx, 0`). Depending on the kind of program you create, this could overwrite important data. In below example program, I chose the .COM format where you don't have to concern yourself about setting up the segment registers. They're all equal to each other.
- When you store a string character (`mov [bx],ax`), you should use `AL`. The character is only in the `AL` register.
- In the sequence `dec cl` `cmp cl,0` `jne p1`, the `cmp cl, 0` is redundant since the `dec cl` instruction already provides the tested for zero flag ZF. And knowing that this is an input loop with a DOS system call, so it's slow anyway, you could just use `loop p1`.
- The message 'inputted string : ' does not truly reflect what you do, does it? Maybe write something like 'reversed string : '?
- Like @Peter Cordes told you in a comment, at the end of the *p1* input loop, the `BX` register is pointing past the last character of the string. Re-use it, but do so in a **pre-decrementing** way. That's the opposite of the **post-incrementing** way that you used in the input loop.
- The output loop can also use the smaller `loop p2` instruction because speedwise the bottleneck is the DOS system call which is slow anyway.

```
#make_COM#
include 'emu8086.inc'
ORG 100h

  PRINTN 'Enter length of string'
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h                  ; -> AL = "0" to "9"
  sub  al, '0'
  mov  dl, al
  mov  dh, 0                ; -> DX = 0 to 9
  printn

  print "Enter String here: "
  mov  bx, OFFSET Buffer
  mov  cx, dx
p1:  
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
  mov  [bx], al
  inc  bx                   ; "post-increment"
  loop p1
  printn

  PRINT 'reversed string : '
  mov  cx, dx
p2:
  dec  bx                   ; "pre-decrement"
  mov  dl, [bx]
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h    
  loop p2
  printn

  mov ax, 4C00h
  int 21h

Buffer db 10 dup(0)
```